# ProGuard giving unclear error

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to export application while proguard turned on and getting following exception

```
[2013-12-06 18:03:21 - ProjectName] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-12-06 18:03:21 - ProjectName] proguard.ParseException: Expecting jar or directory name before '-include' in argument number 3
[2013-12-06 18:03:21 - ProjectName] at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1133)
[2013-12-06 18:03:21 - ProjectName] at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassPathArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:249)
[2013-12-06 18:03:21 - ProjectName  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:130)
[2013-12-06 18:03:21 - ProjectName] at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Normally the line numbers tell where the error is but i am unable to understand what is the reason for such issue

The ProGuard Configuration is as Follows:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keep class com.example.google.tv.leftnavbar.**
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-libraryjars
```

Answer (score 0):

`-libraryjars` takes an argument `class_path`. See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html for more information. If you don't have additional jars to process, you can remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tina Roh's correction, you should check the command-line arguments that are passed to ProGuard -- notably argument #2 seems to be missing a file name.

- If you're running ProGuard as a stand-alone tool, that's easy to check.
- If you're running ProGuard through some other build tool, you'll have to find out which arguments that tool is passing. For instance, there may be problems quoting file names that contain spaces. Upgrading to recent versions may help if there are any bugs.